# How to add bootstrap glyphicons into ruby on rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

I want to have a link to a certain page in my ruby on rails app and I want it to be displayed as a glyphicon ("glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"), rather than "Show". Please help me. This is my link_to:

<%= link_to 'Show', show_schedule_in_teams_path %>

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap gem installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to link_to (If you'd like to use an icon tag etc).

Using FontAwesome as an example,

```
link_to LINK_URL do
   fa_icon 'bathtub'
end
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 0):

this code if you want to show glyphicon using bootstrap

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>'.html_safe, show_schedule_in_teams_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'  %>
```

Comment: are you getting an error or the icon just not show up?, btw I'm using bootstrap gem to answer your question, are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: the icon doesn't show up. do I have to install bootstrap gem first? I'm sorry I'm new to rails.

Comment: my recommendation if you want to use glyphicon from bootstrap you have to use one of bootstrap gem, you can follow up from this link https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have bootstrap installed on your rails application. To make so

1. Add `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to your `Gemfile`
2. Execute `bundle install`
3. Add `*= require bootstrap_framework` to your `application.css`
4. Restart your rails application server

After that, you should be able to use the following code:

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>'.html_safe, show_schedule_in_teams_path %>
```